# How to fire event when drag drop list item to one li to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two li list items. List1 & List2.

**List1 Contains:**

```
A
B
C
```

When user drag A item list to **List2** that time, I would like to fire new javascript function.

Can anyone help me to solve this please ?

Comment: <li draggable="true" ondragstart="myFunction(event)">Drag me!</li>

Comment: $("#list1, #list2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".classList1",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"

    });

Comment: the above script is used to drog list item 1 to list item 2. inside the script i would like to call another function. How to do it.

Comment: You may use start or activate event which is available with sortable widget
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
// Your code goes here
}
});
Source:http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start

Comment: If it's possible to create dropdownlist while user drog and drop the one list item to another list item, that time i would like to create dropdownlist dynamically. Please help how to do that.

Comment: Please create a fiddle & share the link